Deploy iOS MAUI App to Mac? (Not MacCatalyst)
I'm not sure if this is can even be done, but is it possible to deploy the iOS version of a MAUI app to the local Mac I'm developing on?
I'm not referring to MacCatalyst, I want to run the iOS version on my M1 Mac, through the Apple compatibility layer.
I can run it through Testflight on my Mac no problem, but I don't want to go through this process every time I want to try it, also, I don't get a debugger this way...

VS Code supports running the MAUI project on iOS device simulator. Does the document meet your demand?

No I don't think so. I don't want to run in the iOS simulator, I want to run it on the Mac itself, just like I can through the App Store or Testflight, but do it with debugging.

If you want to run your project on a Mac, why not build it with Maui MacCatalyst?

Primary reason is that we use a 3rd party library that isn't built for MacCatalyst, so we currently can't. Secondly, if we can use the iOS one, we are reducing the number of platforms we need to test for.

vs code is supported to develop Maui project, and it supports iOS, Android, MacCatalyst platforms. Did you try this?

First, on Mac, you can debug the iOS program through vs code, in addition, you can implement the project in maccatalyst platform through binding library.
